# Can I freeze egg whites?

Tags: eggs, freezing, food-preservation

I saw [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/620/can-i-freeze-egg-yolks) and it got me thinking, can I freeze egg whites, and if so is there anything I need to bear in mind when doing so?